# How to align text over image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to align the text over the image to the bottomLeft corner, but even aligning it to the bottomLeft it still stays at topLeft corner. So, help me to know what's wrong or missing in my code to acheive the following image text layout.

[image]

My output

[image]

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 220,
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/image1.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Jerusalem",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealBold',
                            fontSize: 28,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text("1,243 Place", style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealBook',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 220,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/image3.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: try and use stack widget

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a stack with fixed height and width, then use a Positioned/Align/ any absolute positioning widgets to place anywhere in the box. *Beware the stack order is last child is first on screen*

The Stack widget will place widgets on top of each other with no responsiveness to each other only to the parent Stack - like Absolute child to relative parent in CSS/HTML

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 220,
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: AssetImage('assets/image1.png'),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Jerusalem",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealBold',
                        fontSize: 28,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "1,243 Place",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealBook',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: What if we also want to make widget responsive for different screen sizes??Do we need to make different screens for different devices for that?